# recv the first few bytes from a socket to determine buffer size

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I'm writing a distributed system in `c++` using `TCP/IP` and `sockets`.

For each of my messages, I need to receive the first 5 bytes to know the full length of the incoming message.

What's the best way to do this?

1. `recv()` only 5 bytes, then `recv()` again. if I choose this, would it be safe to assume I'll get 0 or 5 bytes in the recv (aka not write a loop to keep trying)?
2. use `MSG_PEEK`
3. `recv()` some larger buffer size, then read the first 5 bytes and allocate the final buffer then.

Comment: You won't get zero bytes unless you are in non-blocking mode. A recv() result of zero indicates EOS, end of stream, whereupon you should normally just close the socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *don't* need to know anything. TCP is a stream protocol, and at any given moment you can get as little as one byte, or as much as multiple megabytes of data. The correct and only way to use a TCP socket is to read in a loop.

```
char buf[4096];        // or whatever

std::deque<char> data;

for (int res ; ; )
{
    res = recv(fd, buf, sizeof buf, MSG_DONTWAIT);

    if (res == -1)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            break;  // done reading
        }
        else
        {
            // error, break, die
        }
    }
    if (res == 0)
    {
        // socket closed, finalise, break
    }
    else
    {
        data.insert(data.end(), buf, buf + res);
    }
}
```

The only purpose of the loop is to transfer data from the socket buffer to your application. Your application must then decide *independently* if there's enough data in the queue to attempt extraction of some sort of higher-level application message.

For example, in your case you would check if the queue's size is at least 5, then inspect the first five bytes, and then check if the queue holds a complete application message. If no, you abort, and if yes, you extract the entire message and pop if off from the front of the queue.

Comment: I'll admit, I'm a bit new to C++ (from a heavy C background). I intend to put the recv buffer into a std::string so I can deserialize it with a protocol buffer. Is there much overhead in converting the data stored in a deque<char> to a string?

Comment: @Murph: The point of the deque is that it's cheap to manipulate from both ends. It would be comparatively expensive to handle partial data in a string, since you'd be moving around lots of data. But that's a small difference.

Comment: But if I recv'd the size first, as I was considering, I could pre-allocate the correct size of string and then the buffer would just be filled in consecutively - about the same effort as filling the deque, but it ends up consecutive so i can pass it to the deserialization method that i need to.

Comment: @Murph: That would work *if* you could receive the desired amount of data. But that idiom doesn't fit very well with non-blocking operations (and edge-triggered polling!), where you don't get to choose how much data is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Use a state machine with two states:

**First State.**

Receive bytes as they arrive into a buffer.  When there are 5 or more bytes perform your check on those first 5 and possibly process the rest of the buffer.  Switch to the second state.

**Second State.**

Receive and process bytes as they arrive to the end of the message.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question specifically:

1. it's not safe to assume you'll get 0 or 5.  it is possible to get 1-4 as well.  loop until you get 5 or an error as others have suggested.
2. i wouldn't bother with PEEK, most of the time you'll block (assuming blocking calls) or get 5 so skip the extra call into the stack.
3. this is fine too but adds complexity for little gain.